# merge list with duplicate keys in CUDA

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, set, thrust

Suppose we have a list of structs graph_node*:

```
struct graph_node{
  int from;
  int to;
  float prob;
}
```

Now, suppose several .from and .to elements are repeated in the list. For example: we can have two nodes with the same .from and .to attributes (5,6,.6) and (5,6,.5).

What I would like to know is if there is a way in thrust or cuda to merge these two elements and add their probabilities  (For the previous example having 5,6, and 1.1) or just add all the probabilities of the objects containing the same .from and .to and assign them the added probability to all elements with that key (5,6,1.1 and 5,6,1.1).

Comment: Obviously there is a way. It sounds like you are trying to describe a reduction by key, or a slight modification of a histogram,. Both are solved problems, if you care to do a little research

Answer (score 2):

As indicated by @talonmies in the comments, this can be done using [`thrust::reduce_by_key`](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__reductions.html).  First the list of `graph_node` has  to be sorted to bring like nodes together.  Then `reduce_by_key` can be used to sum like nodes.

There are probably many variations on this, dependent on how you are actually willing to store your data, and whether you want to allow modification of the input list, etc.  I will assume that the data must be stored in a vector of the struct you define, and the output list must be separate from the input list.

In that case, we need to provide a functor for the sorting operation, to indicate how to arrange `graph_node` in sorted order.  We also need to provide an equality test and a summing operator for the `reduce_by_key` operation.  Here is a fully worked example, showing one possible approach:

```
$ cat t13.cu

#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>

struct graph_node{
  int from;
  int to;
  float prob;
};

struct my_graph_node_sort
{
  __host__ __device__
  bool operator()(graph_node &a, graph_node &b){
    if (a.from > b.from) return false;
    if (a.from < b.from) return true;
    return (a.to <= b.to);
  }
};

struct my_graph_node_equality
{
  __host__ __device__
  bool operator()(const graph_node &a, const graph_node &b){
    return ((a.from == b.from) && (a.to == b.to));
  }
};

struct my_graph_node_reduce
{
  __host__ __device__
  graph_node operator()(const graph_node &a, const graph_node &b){
    graph_node t = a;
    t.prob += b.prob;
    return t;
  }
};


int main(){

  std::vector<graph_node> h_n = { {0,1,0.1f}, {0,2,0.1f},{5,6,0.6f},{1,2,0.1f},{2,5,0.1f},{5,6, 0.5f}};
  thrust::device_vector<graph_node> d_n = h_n;
  thrust::device_vector<graph_node> d_kr(d_n.size());
  thrust::device_vector<graph_node> d_vr(d_n.size());
  thrust::sort(d_n.begin(), d_n.end(), my_graph_node_sort());
  int rs = (thrust::reduce_by_key(d_n.begin(), d_n.end(), d_n.begin(),d_kr.begin(), d_vr.begin(), my_graph_node_equality(), my_graph_node_reduce())).first - d_kr.begin();
  thrust::host_vector<graph_node> h_r = d_vr;
  std::cout << "from,to,prob" << std::endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < rs; i++)
    std::cout << h_r[i].from << "," << h_r[i].to << "," << h_r[i].prob << std::endl;
}
$ nvcc -std=c++11 -arch=sm_35 -o t13 t13.cu
$ ./t13
from,to,prob
0,1,0.1
0,2,0.1
1,2,0.1
2,5,0.1
5,6,1.1
$
```

As is true with many CUDA codes, arrangement of data in AoS format may not be optimal for processing efficiency.  Rearrangement of data storage into a separate set of vectors for `.from`, `.to`, and `.prob` elements would probably allow for some efficiency gain, and also simplification of the code.